# Error while building WPF project with Web Browser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

In my application, I have a `UserControl` in which I use a `WebBrowser` control.

The following is the code for the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="tool.ucMain"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="354" d:DesignWidth="440">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <WebBrowser Name="wbMap" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="300"></WebBrowser>
        <DataGrid Name="grdSignals" DockPanel.Dock="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I am using this `UserControl` in another `UserControl` which has a `TabControl`. This is the code for the other `UserControl`:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Name="tabMain" Header="Main">
            <uc:ucMain />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabDataExplorer" Header="Data Explorer"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The *ucMain* is the first `UserControl`. When I clean the project I can see the first user control. But when I build/run it, it disappears and I get the error as shown in the following image. I get this error even in design view.

[image]

Comment: There is no problem with your code. Can you post the reference to uc:ucMain? it should something like xmlns:uc=...

Comment: Can you also post the constructor in the code-behind for the user control that contains the browser? I created a test and duplicated this behavior by specifying an invalid source for the browser.

Comment: @JerryLiang: xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:tool"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to navigate to your local file you should always append `file:///` in the front of your Uri path.

**EDIT**

I just tested it, I can see this error occurred in designer view of the Main Window. I can see Visual Studio tried to trigger the Loaded Event of the UserControl. Somehow the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns the Visual Studio path.

The best way to skip this error might be using `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode()`

For example you can do the following to skip this error in designer view.

```
   private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) return;
        String appdir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        String mapPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdir, "MAP.html");
        ResultWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("file:///" + mapPath));
    }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Is this correct? `wbMap.Navigate("file:///" + mapPath);`

Comment: I am not getting the error any more. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated this behavior by creating a UserControl that contains the WebBrowser, and called that BrowserContainer. Then, I created another UserControl called BrowserBrowserContainer and added my first UserControl to that. After that, I added the BrowserBrowserContainer UserControl to my MainWindow.xaml file for my test project.

When I give the WebBrowser a name, such as "Browser", and then add the following code to the constructor for BrowserContainer, I get the exact same behavior that you describe.

```
public BrowserContainer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Browser.Source = new Uri("c:\\thisfiledoesntexist");
}
```

Naturally, the solution is not to set the Source, or to set it to something that is valid at design time. The parameterless constructor is called whether you're in design mode or not.

Comment: I am not doing anything in the constructor. 
`public ucMain()         
{             
    InitializeComponent();          
}`
 
I am setting the browser navigation in Loaded event.
 
`private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    String appdir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); 
    String mapPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdir, "MAP.html"); wbMap.Navigate(mapPath); 
}`

Comment: That will give you the same result if the path is not found. Have you verified that "map.html" exists in the path you're creating?

Comment: Also, if "map.html" is a resource that you're including in your project, you'll need to set the build action to copy it to your build location (bin\debug or bin\release).

Comment: I have copied the "MAP.html" directly into the output folder. And yes map.html is present in the mapPath location.